# Changing the product image

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, cache, image

From the code below I get the image of a product from a url:

```
$media = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
```

And with that it returns me the image from the URL by picking directly from the product:

```
http://urlsite.com/media/catalog/product/u/m/uma-flor-alaranjada-com-mensagem-cart_o-14896928_1_1.jpg
```

But for my need, in this way, even resizing the image, it gets distorted and I needed to get the image through the cache and in case it would have to return the image from the URL below, however I do not know what I should change to do that:

```
http://urlsite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/50x50/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/u/m/uma-flor-alaranjada-com-mensagem-cart_o-14896928_1_1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting product data e.g

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
```

Then the following should work perfectly fine

```
$media - $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(38, 38);
```

Tested and working on 1.9 this will return the URL so you can use like

```
<img src="<?php echo $media; ?>" />
```

Comment: Returned error 404.

Comment: But I wanted to assign this path in the $media variable, how should I do it?

Comment: have now updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If i understood well you want to resize your image then you get it from a cache, so you have to do this:

in **list.phtml** for exemple:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{currentTheme}/template/catalog/product.list.phtml`, you update the current one with  :

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(50, 50); ?>
```

then you will get it like your exemple :

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/50x50/9df78eab338d27136e95/i/m/image-name.jpg
```

`/media/catalog/product/cache/` = **cache directory**.

`1/` = **store ID**.

`image/` = **subdirectory**. `// image/ or small_image/ or thumbnail/`

`50x50/` = **image size**.

`9df78eab338d27136e95/`= **image cache hash**.

`i/` = **first letter of image name**.

`m/` = **second letter of image name**.

`image-name.jpg`= **image name**.

Comment: This code returns me error 500, as I'm assigning the path to the $media variable.

Comment: Hein ? Dont assign anything, like i explained in my answer with the fonction, magento resize automatically the image and stock it in media, you  hanevn't to set path...

Comment: Yes, but I need to put this value in the $media variable.